# Entity Framework - migration from Database first

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF6 in my project and now trying to migrate to a new DB.
I changed the connection string to use the new database(the old DB doesn't exist anymore) but I am still getting errors like  `invalid object name 'DB1.dbo.Users'`

where DB1 is the name of the old database.
I thought it might be a caching problem so I added

```
MergeOption = Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking
```

but it still not working.

it seems like EF is ignoring the connection string in the config file.

here are my connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SAP;Initial Catalog=IQC_Demo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="IQCReportsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFModels.IQCReportsModel.csdl|res://*/EFModels.IQCReportsModel.ssdl|res://*/EFModels.IQCReportsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SAP;Initial Catalog=IQC_Demo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

as you can see the new DB name is IQC_Demo and the server name is SAP.

I also tried to change `System.Data.EntityClient` to be `System.Data.SqlClient`
but no luck there...

Please advise.

Comment: Have you changed the name of the connection string? If so search your project for the name of the old connection name and replace it with the new one. Also search for db1.

Comment: Hi Rob, I did not change the name of the connection string and I also checked that the names in the code and in the connection string are equal.

Comment: Have you cleared out the database migrations, created a new migration and update-database?

Comment: How can I update the DB? the develpoment was made on another server and now I am trying to just copy the release folder to the production server, I cant rebuild my project there.